# Is it feasible to narrow down the result returned by ls() with grep in R, much like the `ls -l | grep` command in UNIX?

Tags: r, pipe

In Terminal/shell script, you can list all files in the current directory with `ls -l`, and then pipe it to execute an additional command. For example, `ls -l | grep -i "calc"` returns all files whose filename includes `calc`. In R, you can list all objects currently stored in the workspace, with `ls()` command.

However, I want to do narrow down the list returned by `ls()` with something like the grep feature in R, where the input is the returned list by `ls()` and the output is the list narrowed down by grep (or something), much like the UNIX pipe feature I mentioned above. Is it feasible to do it in R?

Also, is it also feasible to narrow down the list by `xargs`-like functionality in R? So I like to get only the objects on which the literal includes `if`, so that if a function on the list returned by `ls()` includes the if-else condition inside it, I want to display the function in console. You can do it in Terminal with `find . | xargs grep "if"` (of course those are files in the current directory, not an R object in workspace, but I showed it just the purpose of illustration).

Note that this is not a post on how to call shell commands from within R. It's not what I want to do.

I use OS X 10.9.3 and R 3.1.0.

Comment: What are you asking? `R` has `grep` commands.  Compiled functions won't have the text string `if` in them.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? R has its method to parse and filter texts. Maybe you should take time to learn R way to do things than trying to apply something that will not be very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls()` has a `pattern` parameter that might be what you need:

```
pattern    an optional regular expression. Only names matching pattern 
           are returned. glob2rx can be used to convert wildcard patterns 
           to regular expressions.
```

For the second part of your question, you could use `capture.output(getAnywhere())` and `grep` to look inside function source. You'll need to pass in the functions to that and I'd make that whole operation a function to keep the implementation clean.

Comment: Thanks. How about `xargs`-like operation?

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I want to get. `getAnywhere("if")` returns only the built-in `if` function, but I want to get all objects that use `if` inside it.

Comment: Right. You'll have to take the output of the `ls()` call then use those names in the `getAnywhere()` call. The `capture.output()` call makes the lines of functions `grep`-able, then, and you should be able to wrap all that in a function that takes arguments of what strings to look for.

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
grep("calc",list.files(),value=TRUE)
```

which should "emulate" `ls -l | grep -i "calc"`. See `?list.files` and `grep`.

Comment: @agstudy: I fully agree for a `list.files()` example. However, it seems like the OP might appreciate learning about `grep()` in R in general.